# how is a testing tool different from testing framework/

Tags: c#, testing, automation, nunit, resharper

What is the basic difference between, a **test automation framework** and a **testing tool**?

For example `nunit` is a test automation framework, but on the other hand `Resharper` is a testing tool. Both are used for testing the `C#` code.

What is the difference between them?

I mean why is one called a test framework and the other a testing tool?

Comment: is Resharper a testing tool?

Comment: @LeiYang yes and no. ```ReSharper``` does many things, including executing and analyzing unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

The **testing framework** is used to describe your tests. E.g. `NUnit` or `XUnit` are used to write unit tests.

The **testing tool** is a tool that executes tests. `Resharper` for example will not just execute your tests and show you how many succeed, but can also measure the execution time of each test, analyze them and measure the code coverage.

In short:

- **testing framework**: describes any kind of tests
- **testing tool**: works with this tests (e.g. analyses or executes them)

Answer (score 1):

In the extremely general sense, frameworks, runners,  report writers, etc. are all tools. In common use, "tools" means an executable that does something with your tests or test results. The most common tool is a test runner. Other tools measure performance or coverage, produce reports, etc.

Since you mention NUnit, it consists of a number of different tools together with a test framework. The NUnit framework is packaged as and often called just plain "NUnit."

The NUnit team produces several different runners, including the console runner and two VS adapters. A GUI is being developed separately (by me). Other runners you can use with NUnit include Resharper, TD.Net and NCrunch.

Answer (score 0):

#### Testing framework

**repeat** steps for check given input and output of given aspects(functionality or quality) in all live of project.

**steps** - one part of test that is execute something or tests aspect.

#### Testing tool

Checks quality of aspects(code, structure, standards) in given situation.

#### Summary

Tools are more technical stuff like, voltometer - you check actual state of stuff.

Framework is like creating environment to execute action (like possibility to press button).

Answer (score 0):

**Testing framework**: Is a framework which is used to write test cases as per expectation like Xunit, Jasmine

**Tool**: is a tool which uses test cases written using testing frameworks and gives analytics of test like how may are pass or fail so, tools are like resharper, vs testing tools are popular

Hope it make sense.

## happytesting